# Converting IActionResult to something that can be mapped in JS

Tags: c#, javascript, react.js, asp.net-web-api

I have the following ReactJS unordered list which is generated from answers:

```
<ul className="mt-2 col-md-12">{this.state.answers.map((v,i) =>
   <li className="list-group-item" style={{"width": "220px"}} 
      key={i}> {v} </li>) }
</ul>
```

I get answers the following way:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    const url = "api/" + this.state.actionWith + this.state.button + this.state.value;
    fetch(url, {
        method: this.state.method
    })
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(data => {
            this.setState({answers: data, input: false, actionWith: "", method: "", button: "", placeholder: "", value: ""})
       })
}
```

Controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult ListTargets()
{
    var answer = _tlConnection.ListTargets();
    return Ok(answer);
}
```

And it works well, when _tlConnection methods return something like IEnumerable.

The problem is, that some of the methods return UInt for example. Then this.state.answers is not something that can be mapped. I solve this the following way:

```
[HttpGet("{targetName}")]
public IActionResult getTargetID(string targetName)
{
    var answer = new List<string>() { _tlConnection.getTargetID(targetName).ToString() };
    return Ok(answer);
}
```

But it feels quite hacky. Is there a more eloquent solution?

Is this a correct way to approach JSON response in ReactJS in general?

Comment: It looks like you should have two different requests and _views_. One requesting a list and the other a specific item. Your current view is doing to much because it's responsible for two different kinds of data. This is why you have to hack the APIs.